# Azure Devops deploy : Task failed while parsing with following error: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I have tried to Deploy an ARM template from GitHub with Azure DevOps Pipeline (CI/CD). I have created a blank parameters file as I am not using it for now but when i click the deploy button I get the following error.

```
Error: Ensure the Parameters file ( 'd:\a\r1\a\Github drops\azuredeploy.parameters.json' ) is valid. Task failed while parsing with following error: Unexpected end of JSON input
```

Here is the contents of the parameters.json

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": { 
    },
    "resources": [ ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter file must be in the following format:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentParameters.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
     "storageAccountType": {
         "value": "Standard_GRS"
     }
  }
}
```

Reading: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-group-template-deploy#parameter-files

Comment: The error now i get is The request content was invalid and could not be deserialized: 'Could not find member 'schema' on object of type 'Template'. Path 'properties.template.schema', line 1, position 36.'.
Task failed while creating or updating the template deployment.

Comment: means your template is somehow broken, like wrong encoding or invisible characters, wrong line endings, etc. it cannot read it properly.

Comment: I notice that in deploy arms template i sued schema instead of $schema and reran a new release and now get the following error 2019-08-18T08:38:47.6454915Z ##[error]Error: No package found with specified pattern: d:\a\r1\a\**\*.zip

Comment: I did as per the suggestion in the following link but doesnt work for me https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/349729/error-no-package-found-with-specified-pattern-dar1.html.

Comment: Added - task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1 to last line of the azure-pipelines.yml file

Comment: this is a completely different question, I suggest you accept this one and start a new question